# For What $a,b$ , $f(x)$ is Continuous and for What $a,b$ , $f(x)$ is Differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let : $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})+x&\text{ if }x<0\\
ax+b&\text{ if }x\ge0
\end{cases}$$

I need to find For What $a,b$ , $f(x)$ is Continuous and for What $a,b$ , $f(x)$ is Differentiable.

my attempted:

for Continuous we need :

$$\lim _{x\to 0^+}f\left(0\right)=\lim _{x\to 0^-}f\left(0\right)=f\left(0\right)$$

$$\lim _{x\to 0^+}ax+b=\lim _{x\to 0^-}x^2sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+x$$

$$b=0$$

so we need b=0 for Continuous .

and for Differentiable we need:

$$f'_+(0)=f'_-(0)=f'(0)$$

but $f'_-(0)$ is Undefined so Is there anything wrong , and how to continue?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. Yes, in order that $f$ is continuous at $0$, $b$ must be $0$. And if $f$ is differentiable at $0$, then $f$ is continuous at $0$ and therefore $b$ must still be $0$. And if $b=0$, $f_+'(0)=a$. So, since $f_-'(0)=1$, $f$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $a=1$ and $b=0$.

**Note:** $f_-'(0)=1$ because$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)+1=1.$$

Comment: but why is $f'_-(0)=1$ ? I tried and it was undefined ?

Comment: @abcder I've edited my answer.

Comment: I got it , thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

compute $$\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$ and the Limit for $h$ tends to Zero, if $h\ne 0$